# Problems-exercises on complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, book-recommendation

Is there any books, pdfs, problem sheets etc, where i can find problems-exercises on standard undergraduate complex analysis? I know every book has exercises, i am asking if there is a specific book with only reasonably hard and easy problems so i can understand the course better. I didn't find any better that's why i am asking here.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Dover has an English translation of the Russian book [*"A Collection of Problems on Complex Analysis"*](https://www.amazon.com/Collection-Problems-Complex-Analysis-Mathematics/dp/0486669130). I haven't read it, but its table of content looks quite comprehensive.